# jQuery .slideToggle() lags in Safari

Tags: jquery, css, safari

I have an interesting problem. On my site [tylucaskelley.com](http://tylucaskelley.com), I am using jQuery .slideToggle() to open up different sections of the site when clicked (try clicking 'about me' to see). However, in Safari on Mac OS X, there is a significant amount of lag. Mobile Safari, Chrome on desktop and Android, as well as Firefox and IE all handle the simple animation just fine. I have tried on a few devices (MacBook Pro Retina, new iMac), and the lag is consistent across all of them. Here are a few relevant code snippets:

**JavaScript**

```
$("#about-button").click(function(event) {
    $("#about").slideToggle();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="menu-item two">
    <a id="about-button" href="#stay_here">about me</a>
    <p id="about">
      some text that is initially hidden on page load.
    </p>
</div>
```

Any help is greatly appreciated; otherwise I may just switch to CSS animations. Thanks!

Comment: Did you try to speed up the animation?

Comment: Yes, tried speeding up and slowing down, but to no avail unfortunately.

Comment: Had the same problem. But then I realized I was loading jQuery two times. Now it works smoother.